# Can't build PortAudio with msys (Windows 7 x86_64)

Tags: build, msys, portaudio

I'm trying to build PortAudio on my Windows 7 with msys and he doesn't build in the specified directory.

I do: "./configure --prefix="C:\Tools\PortAudio_build" and then "make". But he doesn't build in this folder and he shows an error.

What can I do? I'm following the official PortAduio tutorial.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the particular error being thrown.

Comment: libtool: link: only absolute run-paths are allowed. make: *** [lib/libportaudio.la] Error 1